# JS closure not updating null when passing an object

Tags: javascript

Given the code with a closure, why is `make_function` returning `null` when I pass it an object?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/L3nNeiibTMdR6GEnyMOX?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(everything);

function everything() {

  var null_start = null;
  var object_start = { obj: null };

  function make_function (arg) {
    return function () {
      d3.select('#console')
        .append('p')
        .text(JSON.stringify(arg))
        .style('color', 'blue');
    };
  }

  // Make a function with arg=null
  var func = make_function(null_start);
  d3.select('#console').append('p').text('Expecting null here');
  func();

  null_start = {
    foo: 5,
    bar: 42
  };
  d3.select('#console').append('p')
    .html('Expecting {foo:5, bar:42} here <span style="color:red;">Why is this still null???</span>');
  func();

  // Make a function with arg={obj:null}
  func = make_function(object_start);
  d3.select('#console').append('p').text("Expecting {obj: null} here");
  func();

  object_start.obj = {
    foo: 5, 
    bar: 42
  };
  d3.select('#console').append('p')
    .html('Expecting {obj: {foo:5, bar:42}} here <span style="color:red;">if this one is updated?</span>');
  func();
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but do you need a `return` in front of your `d3.select` call?

Comment: yes, because this is making a function that will get called later.  I want it to return a function, not just perform a function.

Comment: Well, I asked b/c you didn't have one. But the issue was apparently elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments passed in JavaScript are not passed by reference, but by a special "reference-copy". In other words, when you pass `null_start` to `make_function`, a copy of the `null_start` variable is passed.

Changes to the `null_start` variable would *not* be reflected by the variable passed to the function.

This is the reason why creating another function with the new value of the variable works as intended in your example.

Note that when passing objects, changes to the object will be reflected by the original variable as well. This is because objects are mutable in JavaScript. For example:

```
function change (obj) { obj.foo = 'bar'; }
var x = {};
change(x);
console.log(x.foo); // 'bar'
```

This is because an object is merely a box of keys pointing to values. Keys inside the object *point* to values, which can be modified, and reflected upon by the outer-scope of the function. But if we pass the value directly, it will not work:

```
function change (val) { val = 'fff'; }
var x = {foo: 'bar'};
change(x.foo);
console.log(x.foo); // 'bar'
```

Hope that helps!